# Use output of query A as condition for query B

Tags: mysql, database

I'm currently using the following query to determine which projects in a database have no associated milestones:

```
SELECT P.project_id, COUNT(M.milestone_id) as count FROM projects P
LEFT JOIN milestones M USING(project_id)
GROUP BY P.project_id
HAVING count < 1
```

and it returns:

```
project   count
---------------
9         0
34        0
32        0
41        0
```

How do I now go `INSERT` a new milestone row for each project_id in that table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `INSERT...SELECT` statement

```
INSERT INTO tableName (project_ID)
SELECT  P.project_id
FROM    projects P
            LEFT JOIN milestones M 
                USING(project_id)
GROUP BY P.project_id
HAVING count < 1
```

change `tableNAme` to the name of the table where you want to insert the new row/s.

**UPDATE 1**

```
INSERT INTO tableName (project_ID, colA, colB, colC)
SELECT  P.project_id, colA, colB, colC
FROM    projects P
            LEFT JOIN milestones M 
                USING(project_id)
GROUP BY P.project_id
HAVING count < 1
```

now question arises, what if you want to have a value which is not present in the column? you can create virtual values for that.

```
INSERT INTO tableName (project_ID, field1, field2, field3)
SELECT  P.project_id, '' AS field1, 0 AS field2, NULL AS field3
FROM    projects P
            LEFT JOIN milestones M 
                USING(project_id)
GROUP BY P.project_id
HAVING count < 1
```

Comment: awesome. what if i want to give it more values that just the project id?

Comment: You just have to add the field names in the INSERT statement INSERT INTO tableName (project_ID, field_1, field_2, ..., field_N) and then address the corresponding columns in the SELECT statement part.

Comment: you can add more rows for that. BTW i just updated the answer.